# React: test component that uses react-measure

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, measure

I am trying to test a component that uses react-measure.

The component is pretty simple

```
class AdjustableIframe extends React.Component {
  props: {
    children: node
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <Measure
        bounds
        onResize={(contentRect) => {
          console.log("I want to handle resize")
        }
        }
      >
        {({ measureRef }) => (
          <div ref={measureRef}>
            { this.props.children }
          </div>
        )
        }
      </Measure>
    )
  }
}
```

I am trying to write a test for this component (since I would like to have a complex logic for onResize method). But I have no idea how to simulate a resize in my Jest test.

I tried to call window.resizeTo but this doesn't help.

Could anyone managed to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
const windowSize = 500;

Object.assign(window, {
  innerWidth: windowSize,
  innerHeight: windowSize,
  outerWidth: windowSize,
  outerHeight: windowSize,
}).dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

This works for me when using `react-media`, hopefully it'll work fo you as well!